# R leaflet custom image to layer control

Tags: r, leaflet

I'm creating a leaflet map with multiple layers in R. I have a layer control created using addLayersControl(). Since I used custom image for markers of different layers, I wonder if there is a way that I can add custum images before the names of the layers to the layer control created by R.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. Since you didn't provide any code I am going to use the tutorial code from the offical documentation [page](https://rstudio.github.io/leaflet/showhide.html):

```
outline <- quakes[chull(quakes$long, quakes$lat),]

map <- leaflet(quakes) %>%
  # Base groups
  addTiles(group = "OSM (default)") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Stamen.Toner", group = "Toner") %>%
  addProviderTiles("Stamen.TonerLite", group = "Toner Lite") %>%
  # Overlay groups
  addCircles(~long, ~lat, ~10^mag/5, stroke = F, group = "Quakes") %>%
  addPolygons(data = outline, lng = ~long, lat = ~lat,
              fill = F, weight = 2, color = "#FFFFCC", group = "Outline") %>%
  # Layers control
  addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c("OSM (default)", "Toner", "Toner Lite"),
    overlayGroups = c("Quakes", "Outline"),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
  )
map
```

If you for example want to add an image before the Layer name "Quakes", add the following standard html `<img src="">` tag inside the `LayersControl()` function:

```
addLayersControl(
    baseGroups = c("OSM (default)", "Toner", "Toner Lite"),
    overlayGroups = c("<img src='http://your/image/path.png' height='20' width='20'> Quakes", "Outline"),
    options = layersControlOptions(collapsed = FALSE)
  )
```

Comment: Wouldn't it require you to add the `<img src="">` tag to `group  = ` as well, so the circles are linked to the control?